# Verify in a PHP server that one request is made from a specific client

Tags: php, security, http, verification, spoofing

I'm writing a mobile game where the user sends his highscore to a PHP server.

I want to verify in the server that the HTTP request comes only from the mobile devices. I want to refuse calls that a malicious user may send via curl or other HTTP clients with a fake score.

What is the standard, usual way of doing this?

I thought that I could encript the HTTP message in the mobile client, but then I would need to release the binary with the encription key, which could be retrieved if decompiled.

Thank you.

Comment: sounds hard to achieve. There is no difference between your game and curl to the server.

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this. Anything on the client side can be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

It is pretty accurate, however it won't stop clients who are faking their User-Agent.

Generally the best way however is not to let the client make any decisions.

Take a game like Eve Online for example.  Every action you make is sent as a user action to the server, the server then validates the action and makes the appropriate decision.
If the server relied on the client to decide how much damage a ship is doing, the game would be subject to no end of trainer hacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to fetch information about the user's client, such as Browser CodeName, Browser Name, Browser Version, Platform, User-agent header, User-agent language, and so on.

There are probably viable libraries out there (maybe something like Flosculu's mentioned) that can aid you with mobile specifically detection, but you must understand that all of those information can be manipulated anyway, it mainly depends on HOW you transfer the data, so maybe you shouldn't be over-thinking this but instead focus on safe data transfer methods.

A quick search pointed to [this mobile detection scripts](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) though.

But again.. you can't rely on anything like this but if it's not too much time-consuming, then by all means add another validation to the script if it makes you feel better :)